# Change of integration on a family of submanifolds

Tags: calculus, probability, algebraic-geometry, singularity

Given two functions $f, g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, how to simplify the derivative

$$S'(r) = \frac{d}{dr} \int_{f(x,y) \leq r} g(x,y) \,d\mathbb{R}^2.$$

The answer is to take convolution for $f \equiv x+y$, and wouldn't be too hard for $f \equiv x^2 + y^2$ as we have a nice coordinate change. But how to deal with the general cases, provided that $f$ is a polynomial in $x$ and $y$?

More generally, the **question** is:

Let $n, l$ be positive integers, $g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth funciton, and $f_1, \ldots f_l: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be polynomials. In general, is there a formula for

$$S(r_1, 
\ldots, r_l) = \int_{f_i(x) \leq r_i} g(x) \,d\mathbb{R}^n$$

and its derivatives?

Comment: $f_i$ and $g$ are arbitrary, how could you expect to have a formula for $S$?

Comment: in terms of $f_i$, $g$, and their derivatives. The only thing I'm not happy with the original statement is that $r$ stays in the description of the region of integration.